# OS X - detect UPS going on to battery

Tags: macos, shell-script, ups

is it possible to get notification from OS X (10.5 Leopard or higher) that the UPS has gone onto battery - i.e. are there any notifications or system config changes I can monitor?

If it's possible via a bash script that would be great!

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Would probably help to state which UPS you're using, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search of [Macupdate for "UPS"](http://www.macupdate.com/find/mac/ups) shows a variety of software, some of which is old enough where it will likely work with 10.5.8.

OS X 10.6 and higher has decent support for UPSes via USB connections and can set shutdown behavior based on a variety of criteria, at least on my home Mac Pro with an APC SmartUPS.

Answer (score 0):

Check and see if [apcupsd](http://www.apcupsd.org/) is supported with OS X 10.5 Leopard.